# Rust で `MutexGuard` は `Send` でないため、`.await` をまたいで利用できないはずなのにできてしまう

Tags: rust

現在 tokio のチュートリアルに取り組んでいます。
["Shared state"](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state) の "Holding a `MutexGuard` across an `.await`" で、 `MutexGuard` は `Send` でないため、`.await` をまたいで利用できないことを学びました。
そこで示されていた例についてコンパイルを試みて、「`MutexGuard` を `.await` をまたいで使用したら実際にコンパイルエラーを起こすか」を確認しようとしたのですが、コンパイルが問題なく通って、実行までされてしまいました。
このコードはなぜ問題なくコンパイルされるのでしょうか？

実行したコードは以下の通りです：

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

async fn increment_and_do_stuff(mutex: &Mutex<i32>) {
    let mut lock = mutex.lock().unwrap();
    *lock += 1;
    
    do_something_async().await;
}

async fn do_something_async() {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let m = Mutex::new(1);
    increment_and_do_stuff(&m).await;
    println!("{}", m.lock().unwrap());
}
```

実行結果は以下の通りです：

```bash
2
```

Answer (score 5):

Rust のコミュニティで同じ質問をして解決しました。

`Send` が要求されるのはあくまでも「`tokio::spawn` で作成されるタスク」に対してなので、`tokio::spawn` を利用していない今回のケースでは、問題が起こらない
ということのようです。

なので、上記のコードは問題なくコンパイルされますが、下記のようなコードではコンパイルエラーが起きます：

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

async fn increment_and_do_stuff(mutex: &Mutex<i32>) {
    let mut lock = mutex.lock().unwrap();
    *lock += 1;
    
    do_something_async().await;
}

async fn do_something_async() {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let m = Mutex::new(1);
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        increment_and_do_stuff(&m).await
    });
}
```